# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel, has-many, belongs-to

I don't know why I keep seeing the below error:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ec_svdiscount_services.sv_discount_id' in 'field list'`

I have edited my database and cleared all cache by doing:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dumpautoload
```

all in an attempt to erase every record of **`sv_discount_id`**, which is no longer in use anywhere on my project. I am rather supposed to have **`svdiscount_id`** which I have created in the controller, models, repository, and all relevant. Please what am I doing wrong? How can I stop **`sv_discount_id`** from showing up.

Comment: If you're using linux or Mac, you can try `grep -R sv_discount_id * | egrep -v storage` from the project root to find any uses of that field.

Comment: @aynber I use mac and my client is using a shared host. when I use the command you shared I get nothing.

Comment: does your model class have the name `SvDiscount` ?

Comment: @N69S Yes it does... I did something wrong using that name???

Comment: @Urget laravel deduce the foreign key from the class name to simplify the relation declartation. You just need to adapt your relations where you use the field `svdiscount_id` instead of `sv_discount_id`. If your error is not from a relation, then you need to add more details on where exactly do you get that error. (more specific debug details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your model name is `SvDiscount::class` when used in a relation, laravel will deduce the foreign key from the class name.

For example:

```
Class product 
{
    public function discount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SvDiscount::class);
    }
}
```

When using this relation in a code, laravel will deduce that the foreign key present in `products` table is named `sv_discount_id`.

One simple solution would be to rename those fields to `sv_discount_id`.

Another solution would be to specify the foreign key in the relation [(documentation)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship):

```
Class product 
{
    public function discount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SvDiscount::class, 'svdiscount_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely correct! Solved my problem. Thank you very much @N69S